# How to query the database with a list of key-value pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Say I have the a table with 3 columns : Id, Category, Name.

I would like to query the table that way :
Get me the rows for which
`{ Category = "Cat1" AND Name = "ABC" }` OR `{ Category = "Cat2" AND Name = "ABC" }` OR `{ Category = "Cat2" AND Name = "DEF" }`

How? Without having to resort to a huge list of `WHERE OR`
I was thinking of using `IN`...but is it possible to use that in conjunction with 2 columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a temp table

```
create table #temp (Category varchar(50), Name varchar(50))
insert into #temp values ('Cat1', 'abc'), ('Cat2', 'cde'), ('Cat3', 'eee')
```

And then join your main table

```
select * from table1
inner join #temp
on table1.Category = #temp.Category and table1.Name = #temp.Name
```

---

If you want to use that approach from the code, you can do that using table parameters.

Define a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ParamTable AS TABLE
    ( Category varchar(50), Name varchar(50) )
```

and a stored proc that will read the data:

```
create procedure GetData(@param dbo.ParamTable READONLY)
AS
    select * from table1
    inner join @param p
    on table1.Category = p.Category and table1.Name = p.Name
```

Then you can use those from the C# code, for example:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test2;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();

    DataTable param = new DataTable();
    param.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Category", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    param.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    param.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Cat1", "abc" });

    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "GetData";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", param);

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // reading here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Best approach from pure SQL, however I am accessing my data from Entity Framework so I am not sure how well this applies to my situation...I'll have a look for sure. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you pass a table variable to a stored proc? It would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

@Szymon's answer is the best, but if you absolutely need to do it in one query you can come up with a scheme to concatenate the two columns into one string and join candidate values using the same method.  Then you can use `IN` instead of a bunch of `ANDs` and `ORs`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Category + ':' + Name IN ('Cat1:abc', 'Cat2:cde', 'Cat3:eee')
```

This has the distinct disadvantage of never being able to take advantage of indexes.  But it's good for a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Indeed, Szymon's answer is the best for pure SQL. I didn't mention that I am accessing my data from Entity Framework so I am not sure how I can transpose this temporary table procedure in C# code...so I'll consider both of these options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Sql2008 there is an interesting new clause VALUES in FROM:

```
select * 
from mytable
inner  join ( select * from (values('cat1', 'abc'),
            'cat2', 'def') as T(cat,name) ) C 
        on mytable.category = c.cat and mytable.name = c.name
```

Comment: this seems to working, but I had to change the last `or` for an `AND`

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary table to store the key value pairs. Then query from your main table joinned with temporary table. Not as simple as adding IN(...), but this is the only way I can think and i believe IN(...) is not capable